# Error Handling in flows

Tags: visual-workflow, unhandled-exception

I have a screen flow for Lead creation. I have, for example 5 fields and then i save the record based on the user inputs. But, what if the record insertion fails? For example, the user has exceeded the length of a field and the record cannot be inserted. What are the ways to catch such errors in flows ? I tried to use a condition after record creation and to check whether the id exists and if it doesn't, to navigate at a screen with an output message. But still i get this kind of error, since the error occurs before the condition. Any ideas ?
[image]

Comment: To handle the error gracefully, you can build fault path. Here are some example on this page: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_build_logic_fault_default.htm&type=5

Comment: @manjit5190 - you should make this the answer

Comment: Sure, I will do it.

Comment: Thanks  manjit5190!